# How to change icon selection colour on Windows 11 desktop?

Tags: windows, user-interface, selection, color-theme

I am using Windows 11 and have noticed some major UI changes since it's release. One such UI change I noticed is the icon on desktop when selected with mouse click a translucent box appears showing that you selected the icon, however the box is very translucent and make harder to see the selected icons.

[image: screenshot]

I have attached the gif,
Any idea how can I make that translucent selection into a solid dark colour which is easy to notice?

Something like Windows XP where whole icon is coloured in selection color, please see the attached image.

[image: WindowsXP style icon selection color is expected instead of fluent style windows 11]

Please help anything be it regedit or an app, anything that would help solve this UI thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see your issue and that does not happen here. Try a different Theme to reduce the effect and make sure Color (Personalization) is set to Custom.

Comment: tried the theme colors already hence posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is annoying, but honestly it's not something I noticed until you pointed it out. It's only an issue on the desktop, not really an issue for me inside of folders.

Not a perfect solution, but you could enable checkboxes on icons so they appear more visually selected.

[image]

Do this by going to **Folder Options > View > Use checkboxes to select items**

---

And just to note, it seems to totally depends on the current wallpaper for contrast.  My darker backgound that came up looks great this this.  But I agree, it's a bad design and should look and work well all the time.

[image: darker wallpaper]

Comment: hmmm right, somewhat helpful but still needs some serious UI changes.